# Issue with pdfminorversion while using pdfx package

Tags: pdftex

Considering the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\pdfminorversion=5
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
   \includegraphics[scale=.5]{ch01.pdf}
  \label{fig:methodology}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The file ch01.pdf is actually PDF1.5 and `pdftex` expects PDF1.4. What modifications do I need to do so that PDF1.5 is accepted.

Comment: I hope it is not a misconception of mine, but `\pdfminorversion` declares a lower bound for the PDF version.  So if pdfTeX expects 1.4 and you provide 1.5 it should be okay.  Could it be that you confused something?

Comment: @HenriMenke Its actually upper bound.

Comment: A quick look to `pdfx.sty` suggests that the `a-1b` option causes `\pdfminorversion` to be lowered to 3; but even without this option, the package would set it to 4.  Anyway, this happens with the version of `pdfx` distributed with TeX Live 2013: give me twenty minutes and I’ll get where I can check a TeX Live 2015.

Comment: I confirm that even with version 1.5.6 (2016/02/04) of the `pdfx` package, the value of `\pdfminorversion` is lowered to 4 when producing PDF/A.  On the other hand, quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A): “PDF/A-1 is based on the PDF Reference Version 1.4 from Adobe Systems Inc.”, so this behavior seems unavoidable. :-(